# Error updating a UI bound collection in View Model from a different thread in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, task-parallel-library, mvvm-light

I am a noob to WPF, MVVM and of course MVVMLight, could you pls help me with something very critical to my project. I need to update a collection in the view from a different thread created from the view model. My ViewModel has absolutely no idea about the View. I have an observable collection defined in my view model:

```
public class LoginViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<DatabaseConfiguration> DatabaseConfigurations{ get; set; }

    private DatabaseConfiguration _dbConfig;

    public DatabaseConfiguration DbConfig
    {
        get{return _dbConfig;}
        set
        {
        _dbConfig=value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(()=>DbConfig);
        }
    }
```

I use System.threading.Task callback to add an item to the collection from the viewmodel:

```
    void AddDBConfig(DatabaseConfiguration config)
    {
        Task<bool> asyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(
        () =>
        {
        return DatabaseUtility.ValidateDatabaseConnectionConfiguration(config);
        });        

        ExecuteAsync(asyncTask,
            (IAsyncResult ar) =>
            {
                Task<bool> t1 = (Task<bool>)ar;
                if (!t1.IsFaulted)
                {
                    if (!(bool)result)
                    {
                    //problematic statement
                    DatabaseConfigurations.Add(config);
                    }                    
                }
            }); 
    }

    public void ExecuteAsync(Task<object> asyncTask, AsyncCallback callback)
    {
        asyncTask.ContinueWith(task => callback(asyncTask));
        asyncTask.Start();
    }        
}
```

I get the following error on execution:

“This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread"

Is there any workaround or inbuilt mechanism in MVVMLight toolkit to update the UI collection from a different thread?

Your help would be a GREAT HELP!!!
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContinueWith()` has an overload accepting TaskScheduler. There are special schedulers for wpf and winforms. You can get it by calling `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx), please.

SalientBrain's answer is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    //(non)problematic statement
    DatabaseConfigurations.Add(config);
    //or perform creating of ObservableCollection
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you pls tell in which assembly/namespace can i find Deployment.Current.Dispatcher()? in System.Windows? or System.Deployment? the latter has no 'Current' property defined, i guess

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you pls tell in which assembly/namespace can i find Deployment.Current.Dispatcher()? in System.Windows? or System.Deployment? the latter has no 'Current' property defined, i guess.  mine is a WPF MVVM application, .net 4.5, MVVMLight Extras V 4.1

Comment: @voroninp: Thanks. I get a compiler error when trying to call Dispatcher.beginInvoke(). It says, that an object reference is required for the non-static method... what to do...?!!

Comment: @Ananth use static property Dispatcher.Currant

Answer (score 0):

Mvvm light has a dispatcher helper class to handle that. See [Simple example of DispatcherHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401538/simple-example-of-dispatcherhelper).

First, initialize DispatcherHelper in your viewmodel constructor.

```
DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
```

Then, use the CheckBeginInvokeOnUI to run from th ui thread.

```
DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(
    () => DatabaseConfigurations.Add(config)
);
```

Note that with mvvm light, properties updates are automatically run on ui thread. Only collections need the dispatcher helper method.