# Why Does Raising PropertyChanged events from a timer cause an COMException?

Tags: xaml, uwp, inotifypropertychanged, windows-10-iot-core, mvvm-toolkit

I'm developing a Universal Windows Platform app using XAML that runs on a Raspberry Pi under `Windows 10 IoT Core`. The app drives a temperature sensor that's on the I2C bus. The sensor class is `MLX90614Thermometer`. The sensor uses a `DispatcherTimer` to take readings every 100 milliseconds (approx) and updates a moving average. When the value of the moving average changes by more than a specified threshold, the sensor raises a `ValueChanged` event and provides the new value in the event args.

In my ViewModel class, `TemperatureSensorViewModel`, I subscribe to the sensor's `ValueChanged` event and use it to update bound properties named `Ambient`, `Channel1` and `Channel2`. These properties are bound to text blocks in the XAML UI. Here is the event handler:

```
    void HandleSensorValueChanged(object sender, SensorValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Channel)
        {
            case 0:
                Ambient = e.Value;
                break;
            case 1:
                Channel1 = e.Value;
                break;
            case 2:
                Channel2 = e.Value;
                break;
        }
    }
```

...and here is a sample data binding for `Ambient`...

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="Ambient"  Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Ambient}" Style="{StaticResource FieldValueStyle}" />
```

I'm using the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), so my properties are implemented like this (only `Ambient` shown, but the others are identical except in name):

```
    public double Ambient
    {
        get { return ambientTemperature; }
        private set { Set(nameof(Ambient), ref ambientTemperature, value); }
    }
```

The MVVM Light Toolkit provides the `Set()` method, which automatically raises the `PropertyChanged` notification for the property being set.

This works correctly if I read a single sample from the sensor in response to a button press. As soon as I enable the automatic sampling mode (which is timer based) though, it starts throwing `COMExceptions`. So this must be some kind of threading issue related to the timer.

Now, if I understand correctly, the runtime is supposed to marshal `PropertyChanged` notifications onto the UI thread automatically; and that does seem to be the case from looking at the stack trace. However, I eventually get a `COMException`. Ugh.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8001010E): The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.PropertyChangedEventArgsMarshaler.ConvertToNative(PropertyChangedEventArgs managedArgs)
   at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ObservableObject.RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
   at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase.RaisePropertyChanged[T](String propertyName, T oldValue, T newValue, Boolean broadcast)
   at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase.Set[T](String propertyName, T& field, T newValue, Boolean broadcast)
   at TA.UWP.Devices.Samples.ViewModel.TemperatureSensorViewModel.set_Channel1(Double value)
   at TA.UWP.Devices.Samples.ViewModel.TemperatureSensorViewModel.HandleSensorValueChanged(Object sender, SensorValueChangedEventArgs e)
   at TA.UWP.Devices.MLX90614Thermometer.RaiseValueChanged(UInt32 channel, Double value)
   at TA.UWP.Devices.MLX90614Thermometer.SampleAllChannels()
   at TA.UWP.Devices.MLX90614Thermometer.b__37_0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at TA.UWP.Devices.MLX90614Thermometer.d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at TA.UWP.Devices.MLX90614Thermometer.d__38.MoveNext()
```

WAT? I don't understand what's happening here. Can anyone see what the problem might be?

Comment: Please note that UWP/Windows Runtime and WPF are two different frameworks. Your question is not about WPF

Comment: Suggestions @Tim: I think you are looking for [tag:winrt-xaml], but I think your exposure is better if you use two tags: [tag:uwp] + [tag:xaml]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After further research,  think I can answer my own question...

It seems that I made an invalid assumption about PropertyChanged events being marshalled to the UI thread automatically. I read that in a few places in articles about WPF, but as @Clemens pointed out in a comment, this is not WPF we are talking about, it is the Universal Windows Platform, which is a derivative of the Windows Runtime (WinRT).

- **Key Learning: XAML in UWP ≠ WPF**. ***You can't rely on WPF documentation when considering Universal Windows Apps***.

Then I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671719/uwp-updating-ui-through-data-binding-from-a-background-thread) which has similarities to mine, specifically that the poster has made my mistake of assuming that he's dealing with WPF. The accepted answer led me to this other [question regarding the MVVM Light Toolkit's `DispatcherHelper` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401538/simple-example-of-dispatcherhelper), which can be used to marshal any code onto the dispatcher thread.

So, it seems that I have to do my own thread marshalling (I really hate this aspect of Windows programming, I wish Microsoft would make a thread-safe UI technology!).

So I have updated my properties to use this pattern:

```
    public double Ambient
    {
        get { return ambientTemperature; }
        private set
        {
            ambientTemperature = value;
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => RaisePropertyChanged());
        }
    }
```

This now appears to work as expected.

I think a lot of people are going to fall into this quagmire so I am leaving this answer here in the hope that people will find it when they need it.

Comment: Key sentence: **XAML in UWP ≠ WPF**

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the runtime does any sort of marshalling for `PropertyChanged` events, which is admittedly a bit irritating.

You probably want to do something like:

```
public double Ambient
{
    get { return ambientTemperature; }
    private set
    { 
        Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Set(nameof(Ambient), ref ambientTemperature, value);
            });            
    }
}
```

to make this happen on the UI thread.