# Keyboard freezes on Xamarin.Forms Searchbar

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, async-await, xamarin.forms

I have a custom implemented control which is very memory intensive (it basically displays a group header and an accordionControl for each group). 
The CustomControls AccordionControlGrouping and AccordionControl both inherit from StackLayout, so I have implemented my own bindable ItemsSource. I actively change the views of the controls when the ItemsSource changes.
I have optimized this change now (using LINQ and BinarySearch and that stuff) to get from 5sec. per search to 0.8sec.

This wouldn't be a problem per se, but each time a user enters a key the keyboard freezes and is therefore very unconvinient to search.

**My SearchBar is bound to the command of a ViewModel like this**

```
<SearchBar x:Name="EventSearchBar"
             Text="{Binding SearchText}"
             SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"
             Placeholder="Suche"/>
```

**SearchCommand**

```
private Xamarin.Forms.Command _searchCommand;
public System.Windows.Input.ICommand SearchCommand
{
    get
    {
        _searchCommand = _searchCommand ?? new Xamarin.Forms.Command(UpdateAccordionControlGrouping, CanExecuteSearchCommand);
        return _searchCommand;
    }
}
private bool CanExecuteSearchCommand()
{
    return true;
}
```

**SearchText Property**

```
private string _searchText = string.Empty;
public string SearchText
{
    get { return _searchText; }
    set
    {
        if (_searchText != value)
        {
            _searchText = value ?? string.Empty;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SearchText));

            // Perform the search
            if (SearchCommand.CanExecute(null))
                SearchCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

**UpdateAccordionControlGrouping**

```
private void UpdateAccordionControlGrouping()
{
  // Do some LINQ stuff to group and filter a global collection of data.
  // And raise the #OnPropertyChanged event for the ItemsSource of my 
  // custom control.
}
```

Now how do I make this whole process async?

I have already looked into [this article](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28899/listview-search-bar) and it didn't work for me.

Comment: How is this related to async-await?

Comment: Are you actively updating the list every time the text is changed?

Comment: Sorry, for the late response. I think this is highly related to async-await because in order to make a solution where two threads work independently from each other you need async, don't you?

Yes, I actively update the List (i.e. ItemsSource) every time the text has changed. I unfortunately forgot to mention, that the customControl "AccordionControlGrouping" as well as the CustomControl "AccordionControl" are both inherited from StackLayouts. (see the edit of the post for further info)

Answer (score 0):

To run your method 'UpdateAccordionControlGrouping()' async you can do this:

```
private async Task UpdateAccordionControlGrouping()
{
    var newgrouping = await Task.Run(() => 
        {
            //do CPU bound work here
            return newgrouping;
        });
   // assign newgrouping to the correct control
}
```

Be aware that if you need to change any data from the view (Bindings etc) you might get a CrossThreadException. You need to use a `Dispatcher` then as seen here: [Dispatcher.Dispatch on the UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980053/dispatcher-dispatch-on-the-ui-thread)

If you work with MvvmLight you get to use the `DispatchHelper` [Simple example of DispatcherHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401538/simple-example-of-dispatcherhelper)

Comment: First of all thank you for this reply!

I have tried this approach now and came to see that now the Populating is going on async. 
However logically when a population is executing and the user presses another key, the key hangs because the gui waits for the background pupoulation to finish.

I will resolve this as follows. Every time the user presses a key and the pupulating is still in process, the populating is cancelled and a new populating thread is started.

Comment: @Shanakor Apart from using `async` and `await` I think you should use a `loader` to escape the `freezing`  issue and also `debouncing` in your approach, it would limit the number of times your handler function will repopulate the data source, its performance would increase. You can see how to implement `debouncing` in Xamarin in this nice article [link](https://www.calvinallen.net/xamarin-forms-debouncing-an-entry-field/).